# Expresso Store not registering memberaccount on checkout

Tags: expresso-store, registration

What I have (simplified) in my template is:

```
<input type="email" name="order_email" value="{order_email}">
{if logged_out}
    <label>{field:register_member} Create an account</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" name="password_confirm">
{/if}
```

And some more fields for address, shipping, etc.

When I check the checkbox generated by {field:register_member} I expect my useraccount to be created after submitting my order. Everything works correctly: I receive the e-mail confirmation and the order is correctly stored in the database. But my useraccount is not created.

I have read the documentation at https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#registering_members but the example seems to be wrong, in the text above the example it states the password field is mandatory. In the example it's optional. But I have both the password and password_confirm fields, so that shouldn't be the problem.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution by debugging the Store Orders model. Store (ab)uses the EE Member_register class to register the new member. One of the first things the register_member() function in this class does is:

```
if ($this->EE->config->item('allow_member_registration') == 'n')
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

So enabling member registrations in the CP fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! This will definitely help anyone else trying to register members with member registration disabled.